# dynamically add <asp:linkbutton>

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a question about asp : i have a list of ids that are returned from the server to my webpage . Can i return it in a div under a asp.net control ? :

> div_containing_link += " <
>   asp:linkbutton id="bleah" runat='server' onclientclick='java_function()'
>   onclick='dosomething' />"

if not , how can i do so ? the particular example is that i want to return a list of people ( friends of my friends -- i'm developing as a project a facebook-like app ) and when i click on them i want to send to the server that we should become friends and make the changes needed in the database .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your div to runat='server' then add each LinkButton control using

`MyDiv.Controls.Add(new LinkButton());`

As long as your div is called MyDiv you can then dynamically assign controls such as in your case hyperlinks to the actual div.  You could also set some properties before you add them like so:

```
for( int i =0; i<20; i++)
 {
  LinkButton l = new LinkButton();
  l.ID = i;
  l.Text = "Hello " + i.ToString();
  MyDiv.Controls.Add(l);
  l=null;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how you want to create the links. If you have a list of IDs and want to use a DataBound server controls that handel IEnumerable as Datasource, you can use a ListView and assign the specific values of your business object to a LinkButton in the ItemDataTemplate

Otherwise, if you really want to use string concatenation, you might have a look at this article http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/3/asp.net/create-a-control-in-the-codebehind-and-retrieve-its-rendered-output, that should explain, how you render a serverside control to a string.